# Dynamically adding and deleting table rows - Yii Framework

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I am trying to create form by dynamically adding rows and deleting it when user clicks on delete button using php code,

[image]

below is my code to render first row while opening the form ,

```
<div class="selector-details" style="display:none">
    <div class='newfield'>
      <div id='container'>  
      <table id="tid">
       <tr>
        <td><?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('field_list','',$field_name); ?></td>
       <td><?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('field_list','',$operator); ?></td>
       <td><?php echo CHtml::textField('querybox'); ?></td>
       <td> <?php echo CHtml::imageButton(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/Trash.jpg',array('class'=>'trash-action')); ?></td>
       <?php echo "<br>"; ?>
        <td> <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('condition_check','',$condition_check);?></td>
        </tr>

      </table>

    </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
    echo CHtml::button('Add',array('class'=>'addfield-button','background-style'=>'none'));
```

how i should make call the above code to add rows and delete particular row when user clicks on the row delete button ? I am new to yii please provide any idea to go further.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $script = 'alert("hello")';
        Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerScript('#test', $script,CClientScript::POS_HEAD  );
        echo CHtml::button('Add',array('class'=>'addfield-button','background-style'=>'none','onclick'=>$script));
```

if you real want to use Yii style, you can open framework code and there is a good code that you want, search : CButtonColumn.php